# Error: No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I was trying react query for first time then i got this on start of my React app.

Although I added QueryClientProvider I top of the tree I am still facing : `Error: No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one`

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <QueryClientProvider queryClient={queryClient}>
        <App />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  ,
  document.getElementById('root')
```

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
      <div className="App">
       <Forms/>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Form.js

```
function Forms() {
    const[createTodo,todoMutation]= useMutation((event) => {
        axios.post('/todos', event.target.elements.todo.value);
    })

    return (

        <div>
            <form onSubmit={createTodo}>
                <label htmlFor="todo">todo-item:</label>
                <input id="todo" name="Add todo"/>
                <button>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>

    )
}
```

Package.json

```
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-query": "3.12.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0"
```

Answer (score 9):

Prop name should be `client` instead of `queryClient`

```
 import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from 'react-query' 

 const queryClient = new QueryClient()

 function App() {

   return <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>...</QueryClientProvider>

 }
```

Comment: Facing same issue.

Comment: @mani_thelearner I found it. the prop name should be ```client``` instead of ```queryClient```

Comment: when I added this. I am getting this error : TypeError: Object is not a function at this line :  ```const[createTodo,todoMutation]= useMutation((event) => {
        axios.post('/todos', event.target.elements.todo.value);
    })```

Comment: Most likely cause you are using hooks in a wrong way?
Take a look at the link below
https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/mutations#_top

Comment: Took me 1 hour to find that this was the issue for me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading the version from V3 to V2 fixed the issue.